# Have inner div elements fade in/out on a loop while user hovers

Tags: jquery, loops, fade, cycle

I've tried numerous examples elsewhere here on Stackoverflow but with no luck, basically I have a simple div with a number of child elements which I want to fade in and out on a loop while the user hovers the article element. You can see where I've got to thus far here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rWXu7/

My HTML:

```
<article class="product">
<div class="offers">
    <div>Offer 1</div>
    <div style="display: none;">Offer 2</div>
    <div style="display: none;">Offer 3</div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
    var tickerID;
$("article.product").hover(function(){

    var list=$(this).find('div.offers > div');

    (function repeatTicker() {
      list.each(function(index) {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
      });
      tickerID = setTimeout(repeatTicker, 2000);
    } ());
},
// Rollout
function(){
    clearTimeout(tickerID);
});
```

My CSS:

```
article {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

As you can see at present the each loop initiates the fadeIn, Delay and fadeOut on all the elements at once whereas I want to 'cycle' through each element one at a time.

I get why this doesn't work as it is but I'm having a blond moment in working out how to best solve the problem.

I want to avoid using something like 'innerfade' as it seems overkill for a single fade in/out loop.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing up my JS code block @Zaheer. :)

Comment: what do you mean by cycle?

Comment: Have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rWXu7/5/

```
var divs = $('div.offers > div'),
    interval, current = $(divs[0]);

var cycle = function(){
    var prev = current;   
    current = current.next();
    if (current.length == 0){
         current = $(divs[0]);
    }    
    prev.fadeOut(function(){
        current.fadeIn(); 
    });
}

$('article').hover(function(){
   interval = window.setInterval(cycle, 1000);    
}, function(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
});
```

**Later Edit**: (supporting multiple products)

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rWXu7/10/

```
var interval;

var cycle = function(parent){   
    var currentIdx = parent.data('current') || 0, 
        prev = $(parent.find('div.offers > div').get(currentIdx));  
    current = prev.next();
    if (current.length == 0){
         current = $(parent.find('.offers > div').get(0));
         currentIdx = 0;
    }else{
         currentIdx++;   
    }
    prev.fadeOut(function(){
        current.fadeIn(); 
        parent.data('current', currentIdx)
    });
}

$('article').hover(function(e){
    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        cycle($(e.currentTarget));
    }, 1000);    
}, function(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: Great stuff, however in my scenario (sorry I forgot to mention this) I have multiple products on one page - http://jsfiddle.net/mJLfq/

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you ever so much - I don't think I would have got there by myself!

Answer (score 0):

Still not 100% on what you're after, but I guessed it was something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/rWXu7/4/

Still scruffy as I could only play around with it on the fiddle, but it should help clear your thinking block

```
var list = $("div.offers > div");

$(".offers").mouseenter(function(){
    list.each(function(index) {
        $(this).show();
    });
    cycle(0);
}).mouseout(function(){
    list.each(function(index) {
        if (index != 0) {
            $(this).stop().hide();
        } else {
            $(this).stop().fadeIn().show();
        }
    });
});

function cycle(counter) {
    var test = list.eq(counter).fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow", function(){
        if (counter != (list.length - 1)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            counter = 0;
        }
        cycle(counter);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is almost what I was after, but I only want one of the offer items to be displayed at a time.., so item 1 fades out, item 2 fades in, item 2 fades out, item 3 fades in, item 3 fades out, item 1 fades in - loop. :)